# creating appimage using source code and linuxdeployqt

Tags: linux, qt-creator, appimage, windeployqt

i trying to create a appimage for my Linux system. Using qt-creator i have completed the programing and ran the app successfully . but when i am trying to make it appimage using **linuxdeployQt** i am facing some errors

```
linuxdeployqt 5 (commit 37631e5), build 631 built on 2019-01-25 22:47:58 UTC ERROR:
The host system is too new.
Please run on a system with a glibc version no newer than what comes with the oldest still-   
supported mainstream distribution, which currently is glibc 2.20. 
This is so that the resulting bundle will work on most still-supported Linux distributions.
For more information, please see
https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt/issues/340
```

i don't know what this issue is. when i visit the website, it is not clear also. So anyone familiar with this kind please put your help here.

Answer (score 2):

> It means that your glibc is too new.

That's correct, to work around this issue while using `linuxdeployqt` you have to choose as build environment an older system such as Centos 6 or Ubuntu 14.04.

As an alternative, you can use [appimage-builder](https://github.com/appimagecrafters/appimage-builder) which allows producing AppImages on newer systems.

Comment: As the author of the tool I use it to contribute other opensource projects such as: Glimpse, GCompris, and OBS-Studio.

https://github.com/AppImageCrafters/appimage-builder/graphs/contributors

Answer (score 1):

It means that your glibc is too new. I think it is supported glibc version comes with Ubuntu 14.04 as it is mentioned in herr https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt/issues/340. I have faced the same problem and still struggling to solve this issue.